# Batch Cropping/Resizing Photos in terminal in a time-efficient manner

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, resize, crop, photo

I'm running Ubuntu 14. Ideally looking for a terminal-based solution.

I have about 300,000 photos that I plan on turning into a timelapse. The photos are all taken in 4:3 aspect ratio, and are 2592x1944 px. I will eventually string them together into a video, but first I want to get the dimensions right.

I want to make copies of each photo, converted to 16:9 aspect ratio, at 1920x1080 resolution. It's also important to be able to arbitrarily decide the specific pixels to crop (not just cut x pixels from top), as I will at first be cropping out different amount of the top and bottom of the video. I do NOT want to distort the image by stretching it.

Since I have so many photos to work with (~150 GB worth), I also want to make sure the process runs in a quick and efficient manner. I don't expect this process to be -fast- exactly, but I am looking for one of the faster methods available.

TL;DR: Looking to use Ubuntu terminal to make copies each photo, resize it into another directory, and crop it to my specified dimensions and aspect ratio. All without taking -too- long.

SAMPLE PHOTO: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeBgY.jpg
I'd be cropping out the Dashboard and part of the sky. Whatever gets it to 16:9.

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing using some python codes, python provide image libraries which is very useful for image resizing and cropping. Check this [Blog](http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/image-resizing-tips-every-coder-should-know/)